# Android custom view childs are not visible

Tags: android, android-custom-view, redraw

I have a custom view named `CellView` and it's containg 3 `TextView` childs. If I'm making a new layout in XML and I run the app It's working fine.

```
<com.example.views.CellView 
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="120dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   custom:textTitle="My title text"
   custom:textCenter="My center text"
   custom:textFooter="My footer text" />

<com.example.views.CellView 
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="120dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   custom:textTitle="My title text"
   custom:textCenter="My center text"
   custom:textFooter="My footer text" />
```

2 cells for each row in my list view.

I have an ArrayAdapter and I'm inflating `convertView` if it's null and passing to my List View. The cells are visible, but the children's are not !

CellView class contains setters and getters for each Object (titleText, titleCenter, titleFooter), and I'm calling getTitleText(), getCenterText() or getFooterText() when I'm creating the `TextViews` in `CellView` constructor.

```
public class CellView extends LinearLayout
{
   // Objects and constructors... etc

   public void setTitleText(String titleText)
   {
      this.titleText = titleText;

      invalidate();
      requestLayout();
   }
}
```

ArrayAdapter **inflating** view:

```
ViewHolder vh;
if (convertView == null)
{
    convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cells, null, false);
    vh = new ViewHolder();

    vh.cellLeft = (CellView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.left);
    vh.cellRight = (CellView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.right);

    convertView.setTag(vh);
}

vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

vh.cellLeft.setTitleText(getItem(pos).getTextTitle());
vh.cellLeft.setCenterText(getItem(pos).getCenterText());
vh.cellLeft.setFooterText(getItem(pos).getFooterText());

// same for right cell

return convertView;
```

I think the child text views are not redrawn. Each call which modifies an object content (title, center text or footer text) comes with a call for `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *user3126670*, in most cases you can attach the View to root to reduce the heap size (less layout levels):

```
convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cells, parent, true);
```

Your layout file should be `<merge>` instead of `<LinearLayout>`